# I want to fetch the data from three tables which have many to many relationship using mysqli statement query

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch the data from three tables which have many to many relationship. Here is the table structure of my database.

**users**

```
uid[pk] fname lname username
 1      John  smith johnsmith
```

**activity**

```
act_id[pk] title
 log       Account Login
 reg       Account Registration
```

**user_activity**

```
serial_number[pk] act_id[fk] user_id[fk] ip_address date time
1                  reg           1       2.2.2.2      - 
2                  log           1       1.1.1.1      -
```

I want to fetch the username, fname, lname, and activities, ip address and date_time.

```
Output: johnsmith    john smith    Account Login    1.1.1.1    1-11-2013 4:00am
```

Comment: Do you want to fetch all that by a single query? Why? Ok, username (etc) + ip is ok by one query. But why do you want activities joined there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting/joining only your fields-

```
SELECT u.username, u.fname, u.lname, a.title, ua.ip_address, ua.date_time
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_activity ua ON ua.user_id = u.uid
LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.id = ua.act_id
```

Comment: One more question. In the particular case like above using statement query, should we pass all of the column names required in the query as argument for `$statement->bind_result()` function. I mean by summing up all the columns of three tables, should we pass 11 arguments?

Comment: Yes, if you are using `bind_result()` you need to pass an equal number of parameters to match your selected columns. That is why it is good practice to explicitly name your columns in your `SELECT`, especially when doing joins, instead of doing `*` to ensure your bind_result param count matches your select column count.

Comment: You mean if three columns were required, one from each table, i will have to explicitly name my columns and i will need to pass only 3 parameters. Sounds Good to me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL joins:

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN activity
LEFT JOIN user_activity UA ON (UA.act_id = activity.id AND UA.user_id = users.uid)
```